# Why is my Login button always disabled?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, command, passwordbox

I have a popup view with `x:Name=This`, on it a button delcared as follows:

```
<Button Content="Log in" Command="{Binding Path=LoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=This}" />
```

This is to gain access to the non-bindable `Password` property, which is a `SecureString` type.

In my ctor I initialise the command like so:

```
public LoginPopupViewModel()
{
    LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand<IHavePassword>(
        LogUserIn,
        p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username));
}
```

I fully expect that when I type something in the `Username`, and change focus, the property change notification will help enable the Login button. It doesn't, so I have added the extra code, and the button still remains disabled.

```
public string Username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _username) return;
        _username = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

If I change the CanExecute delegate like below, only then is the button enabled:

```
public LoginPopupViewModel()
{
    LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand<IHavePassword>(
        LogUserIn,
        p => true);
}
```

Why does this button remain disabled even when its command can execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a sample program and binding seems to work fine. I don't have your complete source code but you need to use RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the delegate command when you want the command to check if it needs to execute. Have you checked if the binding on the username is correct?
 this.loginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); is the key to the answer

```html
    public LoginPopupViewModel()
        {
            this.loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Logged In Click");
            }, () =>
            {
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName);
            });
        }

        private DelegateCommand loginCommand;
        private string userName;

        public ICommand LoginCommand
        {
            get { return loginCommand; }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get { return this.userName; }
            set
            {
                if (value == this.userName)
                {
                    return;
                }
                this.userName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
                this.loginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: The `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` worked fine, thanks. I didn't find it at first, because my commands were declared as `ICommand`, not `DelegateCommand`.